# Maximum call stack size exceeded (sodoku solver)

Tags: javascript, recursion, math

i am triying to create a sodoku solve. but I get the following error:
Maximum call stack size exceeded. Please help me.

```js
let board = [
  [5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
  [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
  [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
  [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
  [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9],
];

const possible = function (x, y, n, board) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (board[i][y] === n || board[x][i] === n) return false;
  }

  const x0 = Math.floor(x / 3);
  const y0 = Math.floor(y / 3);

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if (board[x0 + i][y0 + j] === n) return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
};
```

The possible function check if we can put n in board[x][y] according to sodoku rules

```js
const solve = function (board) {
  for (let x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
      for (let n = 1; n < 10; n++) {
        if (possible(x, y, n, board)) {
          board[x][y] = n;
          solve(board)
        }
      }
      board[x][y] = 0
    }
  }
};

solve(board);
```

The solve function receive a board and solve it using recursion. The board is passed by reference so the board variable at the global scope is modified.

Comment: Please do not add extraneous tags.

Comment: There's probably a bug in the `possible()` function, so it always returns `true` and the recursion never ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your "solve" function doesn't check if a spot is empty before trying to assign 'n' to it.
so let's say that spot (0,0) can fit either 1 or 2,
on the first call you set (0,0) to 1 and call solve(),
on the second call you can't put 1 (because its already on the same line, row and square), but you can put 2, so you set (0,0) to '2') and call solve again.
on the third call can't put 2, but you can put 1.

and so on, you will keep calling solve() with 1 or 2 in the (0,0) spot forever.

when you fix that (by adding a check if a certain spot is occupied), the code will not run for ever (or get out-of-memory), but you still missing the final condition that returns a valid answer from the recursion.

I wrote a simple library for solving Sodoku puzzles in a very similar logic to yours, you can find it here:
https://github.com/weiss-gal/sudoku_solver